# Simpler expression for binomial sum

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Is there any closed expression for the following sum:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{l-k} \binom{n-l}{i} \binom{l-k}{i} \binom{l-i}{k}$$
where $ k<l < n/2$?

Comment: typo in the question "where $ k"

Comment: Does "any" include hypergeometric?  There is a standard procedure for the conversion to 3F2 .